# How to fill up $(0,1)$ with disjoint closed intervals all total measure one

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, contest-math

This is a problem which was proposed, but not chosen, in a Mathematics competition for University students not long ago, and its solution is missing:

> Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=1$, where $a_n>0$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
>   Is it possible to find pairwise disjoint closed intervals
>   $I_n=[c_n,d_n]\subset (0,1)$, with $d_n-c_n=a_n$?

**EDIT I.** The answer is yes (see the Answer that follows). The interesting thing though is that $(0,1)\smallsetminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}I_n$ in  nonempty. In particular, can you show that $$D=[0,1]\smallsetminus\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}I_n$$ is a Cantor-like set?

**EDIT II.** See a relevant article by [Terry Tao](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/covering-a-non-closed-interval-by-disjoint-closed-intervals/).

Comment: the answer is apparently yes, even though the union of the closed intervals cannot be $(0,1)$ (see http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/covering-a-non-closed-interval-by-disjoint-closed-intervals/ : you have to highlight the text to read the proof)

Comment: Do you really think that editing your question and unselecting my answer will motivate me to answer your new question?

Comment: @Phira: See EDIT.

Answer (score 6):

Choose $c_1=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k}$ and $d_1=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{2k+1}$. Iterate for the two remaining intervals and the two remaining sub-sums.